# I am getting a C++ error saying saying my class constructor argument types don't match my parameter types

Tags: c++, types, parameters, constructor, arguments

Here is my constructor code:

```
vertex_array(float* &vertex_buffer, std::string& texture_file);
```

Here is my main application code:

```
float cube1[] = { 0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f,  0.0f,
                  0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
                 -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  1.0f,
                 -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f,

                  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f,  0.0f,
                  0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
                 -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  1.0f,
                 -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f };

vertex_array va_1(cube1, "blocks.png");
```

I am getting the error: no instance of constructor "vertex_array::vertex_array" matches the argument list argument types are: (float[40], const char[11])

I have spent around an hour looking for the problem yet I cannot find anything wrong with the code. I even looked at another example that passed in the exact same argument type but to a parameter of type const void* and it worked on the example however not for me. What is my problem?

Comment: `float* &` - *Why*?

Comment: As @JesperJuhl mentions, it looks like your constructor interface is expecting an output parameter that you are passing an array to and not a pointer to the array.

Comment: Also, you want `const std::string& texture_file`

Comment: Jesper Juhl and Bo R, the parameter type is float* & because I will be passing in a pointer to a float array and im pretty sure the array name is a pointer to the first index of an array which is what I pass in and then I make it a reference because I dont want it to be copied

Answer (score 0):

The first argument you give to the constructor is a pointer to a number of `float`s and the second is a `const char*` which will be implicitly converted to a `const std::string`, so you need to change the signature accordingly:

```
vertex_array(float* vertex_buffer, const std::string& texture_file);
```

You could also remove the reference declaration for texture_file to make it valid but if you are later going to instantiate a vertex_array using a real std::string, it would result in an unnecessary copy construction, so go for the `const` reference.

If you have different sizes of vertex_buffers, you need to supply the size as an argument too or consider using `std::initializer_list` or a container to keep track of the number of elements.

Example:

```
vertex_array(std::initializer_list<float> vertex_buffer, const std::string& texture_file);

vertex_array va_2(
                { 0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f,  0.0f,
                  0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
                 -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  1.0f,
                 -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f,

                  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f,  0.0f,
                  0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
                 -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  1.0f,
                 -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f}, "blocks.png");
```

Comment: Ok thanks for your suggestion it has fixed my error however I still dont fully understand what your saying about why my code didnt work. So firstly, why cant I take a reference to the array? And secondly, why must the string be const? I think you might have explained this already however I didnt fully understand your explanation e.g. "you could also remove the reference  declaration for texture_file to make it valid", why wasnt it previously valid?

Comment: No, when you pass a C-style array as an argument it'll decay to a pointer to the first element, so you'll loose the size info. I you'd like size information to be preserved, it's easier using a C++ container or initializer_list. `"blocks.png"` is a `const char*`. The constness will be preserved when implicitly converted to `const std::string` which is why you can't receive it as a `std::string&`. It would cast away constness.

Comment: Ok so I have added a size variable but will the rest of the arrays indexes still be accessable within the constructor? Also I would prefer not to use the initializer_list or container because I am unfamiliar with them and would prefer my code ot consist of code I am familiar with.

Comment: Also, why is "blocks.png" an const char*? I didnt give it any type it is just a string in my eyes.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by _the rest of the arrays indexes_. You have a pointer to the first `float` and probably a `size_t` for the number of elements. That's all you get and all you need.
Check out number 1 at [string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) describing the types of literal strings.

Comment: You're welcome. If you feel that your original question has been answered, please accept that answer.

Answer (score -3):

I think you may be using your address of operators `&` incorrectly.

Remove Them both from the declaration and try again.

Using them for the array is pointless and literally cancels out what you are trying to achieve.  The second argument is also incorrect because you are trying to get the address of an r-value.

Comment: This is not the "address of" operator. It's a reference declaration.

Comment: well in that case I would like to correct both of your opinions.  Take this article for example. https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-difference-between-address-of-operator-and-reference-operator